# Can't access models in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Ok, so I've installed xampp 1.7.7 and have my mysql database set up and everything. My database in phpmyadmin is named "spree-default-1.1_development" and my database.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: spree-default-1.1_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

When I type "rails console development" it seems to load the console fine:

```
adnan@ubuntu:~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/spree-default-1.1$ rails console development
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3-p194 :001 >
```

However, when I try to access anything in my mysql database, i get an error:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > Order
NameError: uninitialized constant Order
    from (irb):1
    from /home/adnan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/adnan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/adnan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure why i cant access the models in the mysql database. My setup is in ubuntu 11.04, using rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3p194. When i load the rails server in aptana, i can run the server fine with localhost:3000 and it seems to connect to the database no problem.

When i use my Windows 7 setup with rails 2.3, I can access the models with no problem. typing "Order" will give me this result, which i expect:

```
>> Order
=> Order(id: integer, user_id: integer, number: string, item_total: decimal, total: decimal, created_at: datetime, updat
ed_at: datetime, state: string, token: string, adjustment_total: decimal, credit_total: decimal, completed_at: datetime)
```

Anyone know what is going on? I should be able to access the database fine using simple rails queries.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the database, your Order model just isn't loaded at all.

Comment: What would cause the models to not get loaded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current version of Spree (1.1+) you need to namespace the spree objects.

```
>> Spree::Order.first
```

Comment: Yes, this is right. I forgot to update this when i figured that out. I was used to the old spree that wasn't namespaced.